# Jenkins permission error after changing workspace folder

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up a CI using Jenkins in my project

### Steps done

1)Changed the workspace directory to a custom folder `/var/jenkins-test/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`

2)Proper repo URL in the source code management

But I am getting the following error after Jenkins build

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /var/jenkins-test/node-express
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1170)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1200)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are you using windows or linux? Do you have write perimssion to this folder */var/jenkins-test* ?

Comment: Are you running Jenkins as the jenkins user (default)? Is the jenkins user the owner of the directory?

Comment: @Ivthillo yes i have  here is the  output of ownership `total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 jenkins jenkins 4096 Aug 25 15:34 node-express`

Comment: And All files inside the directory? Can you chown -R jenkins:jenkins on the folder and try to clean again?